# From unstack() to dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

### Hello, I am trying to create a new  dataframe from unstack() of an original dataframe.

- My original dataframe (df) is the following:

  ```
  idx = [np.array(['Jan', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar']),np.array(['A1', 'A2', 'A2', 'A1', 'A3', 'A4'])]
  data = [{'x': 1, 'y': 50}, {'x': 5, 'y': 40}, {'x': 3, 'y': 20}, {'x': 2, 'y': 70}, {'x': 7, 'y': 10}, {'x': 3, 'y': 80}]
  df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=idx, columns=['x','y'])
  df.index.names=['date','type']
  ```

And it looks like this:

```
           x   y
date type
Jan  A1    1  50
     A2    5  40
Feb  A2    3  20
Mar  A1    2  70
     A3    7  10
     A4    3  80
```

- My goal is to create a new dataframe (df2) that looks like this:

  ```
       xA1  xA2  xA3  xA4  yA1  yA2  yA3  yA4
  Jan    1    5  Nan  Nan   50   40  Nan  Nan
  Feb  Nan    3  Nan  Nan  Nan   20  Nan  Nan
  Mar    2  Nan    7    3   70  Nan   10   80
  ```

** I have tried the following code:

```
df2 = df.unstack()
```

This gets me very close, but I don't know how to move from here to the dataframe that I want.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you can do `unstack`, then flatten the multiple index

```
s=df.unstack()
s.columns=s.columns.map(''.join)
s
Out[70]: 
      xA1  xA2  xA3  xA4   yA1   yA2   yA3   yA4
date                                            
Feb   NaN  3.0  NaN  NaN   NaN  20.0   NaN   NaN
Jan   1.0  5.0  NaN  NaN  50.0  40.0   NaN   NaN
Mar   2.0  NaN  7.0  3.0  70.0   NaN  10.0  80.0
```

Comment: Thank you Wen-Ben. Only one question: why the dates are in diffrent order? How do you make sure in the code that they will be in the right order (considering that they are dates)?

Comment: @MarioArend sort_index before unstack